# Meteor Angular collections relations

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm using urigo:angular package. In my project I have two collections: posts and users. Is it possible to publish from server an object, which looks like this:

```
[{createdAt: 20-12-2015,
  text: 'something',
  user: { name: 'some name'}
 },
 {createdAt: 22-12-2015,
  text: 'something2',
  user: { name: 'some other name'}
 }]
```

I mean insert user object to every post.

Update: 
I have two collectionsL posts and users. Every post has user id. When I do something like this with publishComposite: https://github.com/Nitrooos/Forum-Steganum/blob/posts/server/posts.methods.coffee then I have on the client side (https://github.com/Nitrooos/Forum-Steganum/blob/posts/client/posts/posts.controller.coffee) only an array with posts, without the user in it.
I have this:

```
 [{createdAt: 20-12-2015,
  text: 'something',
  userId: 123
 },
 {createdAt: 22-12-2015,
  text: 'something2',
  userId: 123
 }]
```

So, when I'll want display a username, I'll have to do a request to every post about user?

Comment: Can't  you just add tge user to the scope and tell the view to display it or are you talking about adding users to the database?

Comment: I want to write something like this in angular: `$scope.posts[0].user.name`.

Comment: So you want the user that belongs to a post in the array?

Comment: Yes. Same as it is in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @ dakolech do u have an online repo for your code base? I feel that a look at your code could give me a more clear idea.